# How to use an external konsole in visual studio code in linux manjora

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, kde-plasma, konsole

I'm new to Linux, and I recently downloaded the manjora distribution. When downloading Visual Studio code I press F5 to debug, but it does it in the integrated terminal.

I would like to know how do I debug my files ( python ) in an external terminal, in this case, Konsole.

If I change settings.json to "externalTerminal", Konsole opens but does not execute the code

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131821) on GitHub may help you.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the terminal is opening but it is not reproducing the code. just nothing happens